# Are these extra lines of code needed to be bug free for array allocation in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory-leaks

For two dimensional array allocation in C/C++ , the very common code is :

```
const int array_size = .. ;
array = (int**) malloc(array_size);
for (int c=0;c<array_size;c++)
    array[c] = (int*) malloc(other_size);
```

But I think we should be writing this:

```
const int array_size = .. ;
array = (int*) malloc(array_size);
int c;
bool free_array = false;
for (c=0;c<array_size;c++) {
    array[c] = (int*) malloc(other_size);
    if(array[c] == NULL){
        free_array = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(free_array) {
   for (int c1=0;c1<c;c1++)
     free(array[c1]);
}
```

to make sure that if one allocation failed we will free the previously  allocated memory.

Am I correct?

Note : in C++ there is an alternative safe method with smart pointers and STL containers, but lets talk about raw pointers here or about C pointers.

Comment: No, you should not be writing either the first version, or the second version. You should be using `std::vector`. If you don't want to talk C++, and want to "talk about raw pointers here or about c pointers", then the C++ tag should be removed from this question.

Comment: `...the very common code in c/c++ is` - In c++ it most certainly is not.

Comment: Sam Varshavchik  read my last note plz , i said i know the STL containers method , just asking about raw pointers

Comment: between using `NULL` rather than `nullptr`, using C casts, using `malloc` rather than `new`, using raw pointers rather than smart pointers and not using standard library facilities, this is clearly very-much not-C++.

Comment: These extra lines of code do not make your program bug free, because there might be bugs unrelated to these extra lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you detect that `malloc` fails, the only thing you can really do is `exit()`.  At that point, you can't safely do anything regarding memory allocation or deallocation.

The only exception is if you're in an embedded environment where exiting is not an option.  In that case, you probably shouldn't be using `malloc` in the first place.

Comment: Generally speaking, you can print an error message telling the user to free some memory, and cancel whatever you're trying to do. (But it's usually not relevant on modern PCs because you never run out of memory)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code is malformed

```
array = (int*)
    array[c] = (int*)
```

this suggests you intended

```
array = (int**)
    array[c] = (int*)
```

Next you claim this is "very common", when all it is is "very lazy".

A better solution is a single allocation.

```
#include <string.h>

void* alloc_2d_array(size_t xDim, size_t yDim, size_t elementSize)
{
    size_t indexSize = sizeof(void*) * xDim;
    size_t dataSize = elementSize * yDim * xDim;
    size_t totalSize = indexSize + dataSize;
    void* ptr = calloc(1, totalSize);
    if (!ptr)
        return ptr;
    void** index = (void**)ptr;
    void** endIndex = index + xDim;
    char* data = (char*)ptr + indexSize;
    do {
        *index = *data;
        data += elementSize;
    } while (++index < endIndex);
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    int** ptr = (int**)alloc_2d_array(3, 7, sizeof(int));
    for (size_t x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
        for (size_t y = 0; y < 7; ++y) {
            ptr[x][y] = (10 * (x+1)) + (y + 1);
        }
    }
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

However, this assumes the language is C, in C++ the above code is pretty much total fail.

Comment: yeah thanks, this is very acceptable i think .... only one allocation and only one kernel call , it makes sense , and fails only ones hh , well ! but extra calculation :/

Comment: @HassenDhia The extra calculation is paid for instantly the moment x > 1.

Comment: Even minimizing the number of allocations, <strike>you still got a memory leak</strike>.  Also, you didn't consider alignment requirements.  Better to have two allocations, one for the pointers, and one for the data (as a single block).

Comment: @HassenDhia: `malloc` (or `calloc`) should not incur a kernel call for each block, only when new pages are needed.

Comment: Also you have strict aliasing violations.  Worse, it is not guaranteed that `sizeof (int*) == sizeof (void*)`

Comment: @HassenDhia: I mean that the `calloc` function is in the C runtime library, and using it is nowhere near as expensive as a kernel call (on average... certainly `calloc` ultimately gets its memory from the kernel, but it gets much more at once than the amount the program asked for, and then splits that block up as needed, and it also reuses `free()`d memory without getting the kernel involved.  The important kernel call is usually `sbrk()`)